# Issue with docker compose db2-express c

Tags: networking, docker, db2, docker-compose, db2-express-c

I'm trying to set up an environment for developing my projects. I need a websphere container and a db2 container.
I commit my own version of the containers in my repo, now using a single command docker-compose up I would like to start the entire environment.
My docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '2'
services:
 web:
  image: <my_user>/websphere-liberty-of-mine
  ports:
  - "80:9080"
  - "443:9443"
 db:
  image: <my_user>/db2-of-mine
  ports:
  - "50000:50000"
 environment:
 - DB2INST1_PASSWORD=***
 - LICENSE=accept
```

The web container starts and stay running correclty, instead db DB2 container starts and immediately stops, the message is:

```
Changing password for user db2inst1.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
New password: Retype new password:
```

How to start alse the db DB2 container normally?
Furthermore how can I explitely set up network and IP addresses for the two containers if my docker-compose version is

```
$ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
docker-py version: 1.8.1
CPython version: 2.7.11
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

Comment: Which DB2 container are you using?

Comment: I startded with ibmcom/db2express-c:latest, there I create a my DB and my data. Then I committed and pushed an image of this container.

Comment: Personally, I recommend to use my own Docker images https://hub.docker.com/u/angoca/ which are based on best practices from different images, and it is OpenSource. Not as IBM's image which is closed source and it is not longer maintained.

Comment: @AngocA I use your andoga/bd2-instance image, there only I create my db and loadet my data. Then I pushed it as a new image in my repo an tried to use this new image in **docker-compose.yml** adding also the _privileged: true_ but also this way the db container starts and stops immediately

Comment: I know that there are some problems executing command in privileged mode in Docker. For this reason, the instance cannot be activated and for this reason the container stops.

Comment: Ok, I nook on wasdev support on [https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/deploying-a-web-application-using-liberty-db2-docker-swarm-and-docker-compose-across-multiple-docker-machines/] and I solve the issue using a basic dockerfile for db2 container and build it in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
version: '2'
services:
 web:
  image: <my_user>/websphere-liberty-of-mine
  ports:
  - "80:9080"
  - "443:9443"
 db:
  image: <my_user>/db2-of-mine
  ports:
  - "50000:50000"
  command: su - db2inst1 -c "db2start" # Add this line and it should work
 environment:
 - DB2INST1_PASSWORD=***
 - LICENSE=accept
```

I had the same issue before and noticed that ibmcom/db2express-c doesn't start automatically.